# Generate iReport from Jtextfield Value of recent window to iReport textfield

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, ireport

I want to generate iReport from the value of JtextField in my recent window and not from database.

Example I have this txtCategory (jTextfield) in my CategoryPanel. Now when I clicked the PRINT Button, I want to get the textvalue of txtCategory and put that in one textfield inside iReport/JasperReport. How am I going to do that? Can someone help me? I am using iReport Plugin in my Netbeans compiler. Thank you.

Comment: The *iReport* is just a gui designer for constructing report's templates. What do you mean: `I want to generate iReport `?

Comment: I mean I want to generate report usig iReport/JasperReport Template. I am using this through my database. By executing sql query Im getting the report I want to save in pdf/print. But now, I want to generate the report data from jTextfield(not from database) to textfield in iReport.

Comment: You can use [JavaBean Data Sources](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/index.html#javabeandatasources)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you can pass your jTextField data through parameter into report.

```
JasperReport jasperReport;
JasperPrint jasperPrint;
HashMap params = new HashMap();
FileInputStream reportStream;
try {
    FileInputStream reportStream = new FileInputStream(new File("report.jasper");
    HashMap params = new HashMap();
    params.put("TEXT_VALUE", jTextField.getText());
    JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(reportStream);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(
                jasperReport, params, DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8", root, root));
    JasperViewer jReportsViewer = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint, false);
    jReportsViewer.setFitWidthZoomRatio();
    jReportsViewer.setVisible(true);
    reportStream.close();
```

In you report you have to create parameter TEXT_VALUE of class java.lang.String or Object. After that you need to define it in your textField as $P{TEXT_VALUE}...
I hope this is the answer you are looking for.